# messageReaction.emoji.name throws error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here is my code (Discord.js v12) in an event 'messageReactionAdd':

```
module.exports = (messageReaction, user) => {
    if (messageReaction.emoji.name === '✅') {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Why property `emoji` of messageReaction is undefined?

When I use it it gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'`

[Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=emoji) it says that I can  access the name of the emoji.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: What argument did you pass for `messageReaction`?

Comment: I didn't pass any. I had to give the variable of messageRaction to the messageReactionAdd event (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd] like it requires me to do)

Comment: Oh my gosh I'm so blind. I completely looked over you saying that in the original question. My bad 

Comment: If you `console.log(messageReaction)`, what does it return?

Comment: It spits out like a 1000 lines of all the bot's cache(i think that's it?) including all channels, commands, events, users and other stuff.

Comment: Try `console.log(Object.keys(messageReaction))` and see if `emoji` is included in the returned array

Comment: This is what got returned

```'_events', '_eventsCount',
'_maxListeners', '_timeouts',
'_intervals', '_immediates',
'options', 'rest',
'ws', 'actions',
'voice', 'shard',
'users', 'guilds',
'channels', 'presence',
'user', 'readyAt',
'config', 'Discord',
'commands'```

Comment: So apparently the `messageReaction` parameter is being passed as the `client` object. Are you using an event handler? If so, could you show me that?

Comment: I fixed it! The weird reason was that the variable messageReaction was being set to the Client class and I fixed it just by doing this: 
`module.exports =  (client, messageReaction, user)`
But thank you for your help anyway @Lioness100 :)

Comment: Oh, great! Glad I could help 